# How do you evaluate two regular expressions within the same function? - updated!

Tags: javascript

For example, I want to test a postcode is valid so I test the postcode using my regular expressions in a 'if else' scenario and call the function when the form is submitted.

```
function validatePostal(postalCode)
var re = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{1,2})[ ]([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$/); 
var re2 = new RegExp(/^([cC]{1})([aA]{1})(2|18|17)[ ]([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$/);
var str = shipPostalCode.value; 
if (re.test(str))
{
return true; 
}
else if (re2.test(str))
{
return true;
alert("Congratulations!!"); 
}
else
{
alert("That is not a valid postcode. Please verify your input. Format should be AA11 11AA"); 
return false;
}
}

onclick="return (validatePostal(postalCode)"
```

How would i go about testing said postcode against another regular expression and then if the postcode is valid, only displaying a message to those in a particular area.
e.g. those who entered CA4 would get a message and those who entered DA4 would not?

Comment: What did you try so far? Some code would help.

Comment: Is this not just a case of moving your `if` statements around and sticking another one in there? Indeed, why are the re.test() and re2.test() conditions leading to two different blocks?

Comment: Sorry im really new at this so any help would be appreciated. I wanted to check first that the postcode was valid and then once that has been checked as true, it checks to see if the postcode is in the designated area?

Comment: Okay, I have posted an answer below. Please tell me if that is what you are looking for, or alternatively what else you meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so assuming that both `re` and `re2` are the regular expressions for postcodes you want to accept, you could have a structure like:

```
if (re.test(str) || re2.test(str))
{
    return true; 
}
else
{
    alert("That is not a valid postcode. Please verify your input. Format should be AA11 11AA"); 
    return false;
}
```

Now if you want to do another check, like you said about "DA4" versus "CA4", you would have another regular expression for that (lets call it `re3` to be consistent), and you could then have an inner `if` statement, like so:

```
if (re.test(str) || re2.test(str))
{
    if (re3.test(str)) {
        alert("You entered a CA4 postcode!");
    } else {
        alert("You did not enter a CA4 postcode :(.");
    }

    return true; 
}
else
{
    alert("That is not a valid postcode. Please verify your input. Format should be AA11 11AA"); 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function validatePostal(postalCode)
var re = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{1,2})[ ]([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$/); 
var re2 = new RegExp(/^([cC]{1})([aA]{1})(2|18|17)[ ]([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$/);
var str = shipPostalCode.value; 
var isPostalCodeValid = false;
if (re.test(str))
{
isPostalCodeValid = true; 
}
else if (re2.test(str))
{
alert("Congratulations!!");
isPostalCodeValid = true;
}

if(isPostalCodeValid){
    //Check for Postalcode and show mssg or not
}else{
     alert("That is not a valid postcode. Please verify your input. Format should be AA11 11AA"); 
     return false;
}
}

onclick="return (validatePostal(postalCode)"
```

Comment: Thank you, ive tried to put this into my code but no alerts appear at all?

Comment: Why don't you try debugging it using Firebug for Firefox or IE debugger or Using Chrome. It will tell you which condition are you reaching into and why alerts are not displaying or whether there is a problem with the Javascript.

Comment: Well in that case `re` is testing true. So, it enters the first `if (re.test(str))`, sets `isPostalCodeValid` to true, then goes down to the `if(isPostalCodeValid)` section and enters that, where nothing happens. *All* Abhishek has done is re-write your code in a slightly different format, not changing (almost) any of the meaning.

Did you mean to check `re` first, and then **if it was true** check `re2`?

Comment: Thank you for all your help!!!! I have finally got it displaying messages using the || method that was described! I am going to keep trying to get the way above working too. Thanks for taking the time to help a newbie out!

Comment: The "//Check for Postalcode and show mssg or not" was meant for @ez87 to add the code. I am sorry if you expected me to write the whole logic for you @ez87

Comment: @Abhishek Firstly, I apologise if my comment came off as sarcastic/negative - on re-reading I see how the emphasis gives it that impression. What I meant was that (as far as I can see) your code has exactly the same semantic meaning as his did (apart from making the "congratulations" alert actually ever show.) So, if his code did not do what he wanted, then neither would your semantically equivalent re-write.